Errores al iniciar servidor de Angular
estoy armando un proyecto en angular, estoy teniendo el siguiente problema que es al ejecutar el ng serve, la web inicia correctamente pero luego de un rato salen los suigientes errores en la consola del navegador

La lista es mucho mas grande pero es lo que entraba en la foto.
Aclaro que todavia no puse codigo en el proyecto, solo lo cree y di ng serve.

¡Hola Julián!
Veo que el origen del error no es de tu propio proyecto si no de tu browser.
Verifica si es que tienes extensiones que afectan en la navegación, pero, si tuvieras errores al arrancar, simplemente el serve se bloquearía en un instante y te saldría un dialogo de error en tu pantalla.

muchas gracias, efectivamente era eso, desistale extensiones y  no hay mas errores
